# How to access the attributes of a struct in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-manipulation

I have a simple program that makes a 2d array of a struct. I want to know how to manipulate the struct's attributes. This is my attempt; i keep getting Segmentation fault, the problem happens in the fillarr method;

My problem is that i don't quite understand how to manipulate the data once it is in a 2D array. I understand that arrays are pointers, my assumption at first was that i could do something like

```
arr[h][w]->one = 'b';
```

Which i now know is obviously wrong because the compiler really doesn't like it.
Now, when i try

```
arr[h][w].one = 'a'
```

The compiler doesn't complain about that syntax, but this is where my segmentation fault triggers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  char one;
  char two; 
};

typedef struct node node; 

node** makeArr(int h, int w) {
  printf("Making arr\n"); 
  node** output = (node**)malloc(sizeof(node*) * h);

  for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    output[i] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) * w); 
  }

  return output; 
}

void killarr(node **arr, int h, int w) {
  printf("Killing arr\n"); 
  for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    free(arr[i]); 
  }
  free(arr);
}

void fillarr(node **arr, int h, int w) {
  printf("Filling arr\n"); 
  char x = 'a'; 
  for (int i = 0 ; i < h; i++) {
    for(int m = 0; m < w; m++){
      arr[h][w].one = x++; // <- here exactly
      
      arr[h][w].two = x++; // <- here too
   
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int h = 10;
  int w = 10; 
  node **arr = makeArr(h, w); 
  fillarr(arr, h, w); 

  killarr(arr, h, w); 
}
```

Comment: What purpose does `x++` serve given that you never use `x`?

Comment: @Chris i edited the code. Its meant to change the char assigned to the attribute

Comment: I might suggest simplifying it to `arr[h][w].one = x++;`

Comment: @Chris sure. But the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time through the inner loop you're accessing `arr[h][w]`. But since `h` and `w` are the array bounds, you're accessing out of bounds, leading to undefined behavior.

You likely meant:

```
arr[i][m].one = x++;      
arr[i][m].two = x++;
```

Comment: Yep, that has to be the dumbest mistake i've done in weeks.

Comment: Hey, I spotted the `x` thing before seeing that mistake, which just goes to show that it's been a long day.